# Conditional compilation using MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in Xcode for a Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, conditional-compilation

In a Cocoa application, I'd like to use conditional compilation, like:

```
#if MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET <= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4    
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeFileAtPath:path handler:nil];
#else
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
#endif
```

My hope is that this will avoid compiler warnings about removeFileAtPath: being deprecated when MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6, since it shouldn't be compiling that line.

It doesn't work.

When MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6 I get a warning that removeFileAtPath: is deprecated. But it shouldn't be compiling that line, so it shouldn't be warning about it having a deprecated method!

(I am setting MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in both the project build settings and the target build settings. I have BASE_SDK set to 10.6 and specify GCC 4.2 in both, too.)

What am I doing wrong? Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of conditional compilation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is mostly used to perform a weak-linking. You should use `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` instead to perform conditional compilation:

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeFileAtPath:path handler:nil];
#else
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
#endif
```

See [Ensuring Backwards Binary Compatibility - Weak Linking and Availability Macros on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2064/_index.html) from Apple for more examples.